# Redirect to random page with http response code

Tags: php, redirect

I have a page photo.php. This page is called always with parameter "name", so I show the photo which was called: photo?name=milan-duomo-at-night-3

If someone opens the page without any parameter - I redirect him to the random page:

```
header("location: photo?name=".row['name']);
```

I cannot use the default http 301 code. Which one should I send, 307? Or it's a bad idea to redirect to the random page?

Comment: why redirect? if no parameter is given then display a random phioto. is this not possible?

Comment: @Paolo it's possible, but... I was writing a response, and then I understand, I can proibite index of the page "photo" without parameters, so googlebot doesn't check it.. Oh.

Answer (score 0):

I would advice you to just handle the 'unknown situation'. Why redirecting to a random page? Just check if the name `isset` and isn't empty. If it is, just show a message "no photo selected" (or whatever you want).

```
if(!isset($_GET['name']) || $_GET['name'] == "")
{
    //Do whatever you want to do..
    //E.g. :
    echo "Photo not found.";
}
```

Also some small notice. `header("location: photo?name=".row['name']);` won't work. I think you forgot the `$` sign before `row['name']`.

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking that it will be nice to get a photo always. Even if you don't pass the parameter. I'll post an error message with a link to random photo so users doesn't stack there...

Comment: You can use a default picture ofcourse. Then between the `if` check you can do something like `$_GET['name'] = "my-default-picture"`.